# How to create a dynamic model-form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to write a project where employers can post job vacancies. I want to be able to save the job description as a model using a model-form but I also want to allow the user to specify how many requirements there are for a job. So one job might specify 4 job requirements while another might specify 6. So saved models will vary depending on how much requirements were specified.

Is there anyway to create a dynamic model-form where the user can specify how many fields there are in the form and model? I've been researching this for a while but yet to find a simple explanation.

Comment: Your problem sounds like you need a 1-to-n relation from `Job` to `JobRequirement`, not a dynamic model form. Also, do you have some code already to show on your models and forms?

Comment: Indeed, job requirements wouldn't be fields as you describe, but records in another model with a one to many relationship. If you talk about fields perse, you can use a dict inside the job model where keys will act somehow as fields.